# Codeigniter 4: run phpUnit from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit, codeigniter-4

I'd want to run my tests from a controller and display the output in the browser.

I tried with this code:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
/**
 * Run tests and display output.
 */
public function test(): string
{
    $out = [];
    exec('./vendor/bin/phpunit', $out, $ret);
    return implode('\n', $out);
}
}
```

But when I go to localhost:8080/Home/test it return an empty page.

The `$ret` variable contains `1` after the exec, and the `$out` array remains empty.

If I call `./vendor/bin/phpunit` from the command line it works correctly.

I'm pretty sure that it's a matter of paths and maybe permissions. I tried also the paths `../vendor/bin/phpunit` and `../../vendor/bin/phpunit` but nothing changes.

UPDATE:

changing the content of the method to

```
return `./vendor/bin/phpunit`;
```

throws an exception because it return null instead of a string.

Putting phpunit and phpunit.bat inside the public folder and changing the code to

```
return `phpunit`;
```

return the string `Could not open input file: [project path]\public\/../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

UPDATE 2:

the last error is solved by copying the folder vendor/phpunit one level in the root of the project. But still it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

exec, shell_exec etc. are disabled for security reasons. If you have root access you can enable them in the php.ini file (search `disabled_functions`), otherwise there is nothing to do.